# Algorithm that determines a relationship between a square and rectangle

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I need to find an algorithm which determines a relationship between a square and rectangle. It must be able to determine if:

- The square is completely inside the rectangle
- The square is partially inside (overlaps) the rectangle
- Square's corner only touches a rectangle's corner
- Square's edge is on the rectangle's edge

And here are the inputs (given values) that will help us to extract a mathematical formula for each case:

- x coordinate of the center of the square = squareX
- y coordinate of the center of the square = squareY
- width of the square = squareW
- x coordinate of the center of the rectangle = recX
- y coordinate of the center of the rectangle = recY
- width of the rectangle = recW
- length of the rectangle = recL

P.S: Rectangle's sizes are always bigger than the square's width.

I will write the code in Java once we can extract an algorithm using mathematical operations.

**Edit:**

For the case of corners in touch, here is the code I wrote, and it works (Math.abs means the absolute value):

```
((Math.abs(Math.abs(recX-squareX)-(recW+squareW)/2))<=0.001) && ((Math.abs(Math.abs(recY-squareY)-(recL+squareW)/2))<=0.001)
```

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you. As it is, this is a work description, not a question.

Comment: how are x and y exactly defined (left upper corner, center,...)?

Comment: Did you even attempt this problem?

Comment: Yes, I did attempt, and I was able to do the case of corners. Please check the post, I edited. But I still need help for the rest of the algorithm.

Comment: @lweller, I fixed that in the post. All coordinates refer to the center of the shapes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**updated for doubles**

```
double dx = Math.abs(rectX - squareX);
double dy = Math.abs(rectY - squarey);
double dw2 = (rectW + squareW) / 2;
double dh2 = (rectL + squareW) / 2;

if (Double.compare(dx, dw2) == 0 && Double.compare(dy, dh2) == 0)
    return CORNER_TOUCH;
else if (Double.compare(dx, dw2) > 0 || Double.compare(dy, dh2) > 0)
    return OUTSIDE;
else if (Double.compare(dx, dw2) == 0 || Double.compare(dy, dh2) == 0)
    return EDGE_TOUCH;
else if (Double.compare(dx, rectW - dw2) <= 0 &&
        Double.compare(dy, rectL - dh2) <= 0)
    return INSIDE;
else 
    return OVERLAPS;
```

Comment: Just from the fact that you have an else statement that returns OVERLAPS indicates to me that this solution is wrong...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Everything works fine except the edges and the corners.

Comment: @Falmarri, No, this just indicates that you haven't read solution

Comment: @Dave if you work with double values, this solution needs to be adopted

Comment: Thanks, I adopted it to doubles by using the difference rather than equality.

Answer (score 1):

```
squareX1 = squareX - squareW/2
squareY1 = squareY - squareW/2
squareX2 = squareX + squareW/2
squareY2 = squareY + squareW/2

recX1 = recX - recW/2
recY1 = recY - recL/2
recX2 = recX + recW/2
recY2 = recY + recL/2

inside = squareX1 > recX1 && squareX2 < recX2 && squareY1 > recY1 && squareY2 < recY2
overlaps = squareX1 < recX2 && squareX2 > recX1 && squareY1 < recY2 && squareY2 > recY1
```

the last two one should be trivial

Comment: Does this handle the negative coordinates too? Where should we add absolute value?